# Ternary comparison outputs new value

Tags: conditional-operator, powershell-7.0

```
PS C:\Users\Scott> $openlog = "YES"
PS C:\Users\Scott> ($openlog -eq "YES") ? ($openlog = "NO") : ($openlog = "YES")
NO
PS C:\Users\Scott> ($openlog -eq "YES") ? ($openlog = "NO") : ($openlog = "YES")
YES
PS C:\Users\Scott> ($openlog -eq "YES") ? ($openlog = "NO") : ($openlog = "YES")
NO
PS C:\Users\Scott> ($openlog -eq "YES") ? ($openlog = "NO") : ($openlog = "YES")
YES
PS C:\Users\Scott>
```

This works, ie it toggles the value, but it also writes it to the console.  Why? How do I do this properly and not output the new value, without using `| Out-Null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below to set the variable without outputting to console.

`$openlog = $openlog -eq "YES" ? "NO" : "YES"`

I do not yet know why your example outputs to the console. I went through the [implementation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/218/files) and this was a use case that was never handled and isn't handled during testing.

Update: as mklement0 mentions below

> enclosing an assignment in `(...)` passes the value being assigned *through*

Answer (score 2):

[Otter's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641449/45375) offers the optimal solution for your use case, which *bypasses* the problem with your code:

As for:

> it also writes it to the console. Why?

**PowerShell allows you to use *assignments* as *expressions***, by enclosing them in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

That is, **something like `($var = 'foo')` also *outputs* the value being assigned**, in addition to assigning to variable `$var`:

```
PS> ($var = 'foo')
foo
```

That is, the value is output to PowerShell's *success output stream* (see the conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) help topic), which by default goes to the host (console).